# Callback in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

As iam exploring Nodejs,i need to know what's a callback?.Can anybody help me.Since i have referred many blogs and tutorials.But still iam not clear.Can anybody explain with simple example and refer forums related to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A callback is just a function that you call when an action has taken place. For example:

```
var myCallback = function(){
        console.log("Callback Run");
    };

setTimeout(myCallback, 1000);
```

Callbacks are typically used in asynchronous code (such as Ajax calls). The code is passed a function to run when it completes, such as this jQuery:

```
var doAnAjaxCall = function(success_callback, fail_callback){
       $.ajax({
           url: 'test.html',
           success: function(data){
               data.date = new Date(data.date);
               callback(data);
           },
           fail: fail_callback
       });
   },
   okCallback = function(data){
       console.log(data.date);
   },
   failCallback = function(){
       console.error(arguments);
   };

doAnAjaxCall(okCallback, failCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example can be:

```
function sum (a, b, callback) {
  callback (a + b);
}
```

You can call the function `sum`in this way:

```
sum (1, 1, function (res) {
  console.log ('Result of the sum is ' + res);
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the actual parameters are:

- a = 1
- b = 2
- callback: function (res) { ... }

Comment: i have one doubt,even if am assinging callback to the varible ,also it works.,for e.g:   var app = require('express');
var sample = function(a,b,callback){
  var b = callback(a+b);
  }
  sample(1,2,function(res){
  console.log("Result of the sum is:", +res);
  });

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) could clarify your doubt.